# my keyboard has no keys for volume control, how can i make a macro or something to easily control the volume

Tags: macros, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, volume

I just bought a new keyboard but I can't find anything in google for my problem. If you can suggest me a program or anything else it would be really appreciated.

I tried searching it on google and I actually couldn't find a clear answer for 20 minutes. I don't know if I am braindead or something and missed the solution to my problem, but I study computer science so I should know how to google.

Comment: This was pretty easy to find; https://superuser.com/questions/82229/how-can-i-control-the-master-volume-in-windows

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what OS(Operating System) you have.

If you have MacOS (apple on the top left corner), you can change that in System Preferences/Settings (as well as add the volume to the menu bar) or through the Control Center (2 switches on the top right)

If you have Windows, then you can change that in the speaker Icon in the notification area (bottom right) or using settings (just search for Audio)

Hope this will help